# NSRange with incorrect paremeters?

Tags: ios, nsrange

I am building this code to reverse a string, and all I need from you is why the parameters of the NSRange aren't working.

**CODE:**

```
for (int i = 0;  i <= oldString.length; i++) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, oldString.length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is not sufficient, also if it work, doesn't do nothing.

Moreover, your app crash because `NSRange` takes 2 parameters: `location` and `length`.
So until `location` is 0, `length` can be `oldString.length` (i.e. all the string), otherwise, when `location` is > 0 and set as length `oldString.length`, it goes **out of bounds**.

Use this function where i use properly `NSMakeRange` as well:

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)string {

    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString new];

    for (int i = (int)[string length]-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        [newString appendString:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    }

    return [newString copy];
}
```

Comment: That does not fully answer the OP's question.  You could expand your answer to explain why your use of `NSMakeRange` works and his doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is this:

```
for (int i = 0;  i <= oldString.length; i++) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, oldString.length); 
}
```

Now first of all, as Matteo has told you, it has no effect. All it does is make a bunch of ranges without using them.

But also let's look at those ranges! Just consider the successive values of `range`. Study your own code. Suppose our string `oldString` is `12345`. Then its length is 5. Then the ranges would cover these strings in succession:

```
12345
2345[and one too far]
345[and two too far]
45[and three too far]
5[and four too far]
```

Those are pretty silly ranges!